# Running a dll using rundll32.exe.. no output or error seen

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, window, rundll32

I am running a dll using a rundll32.exe but I dont see the output as expected 
nor my log statements 
nor do I see any error of any sort.

How do I debug this ?

Thanks,

KG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows there are programs of two kinds: Console program and window programs. For console programs the system allocates and attaches their console during process startup.

For Windows programs this does not happen so stdout, stderr etc. go to nowhere. Windows program can still allocate (`AllocConsole()`) and attach (`AttachConsole()`) (at most one) console explicitly in their code. So you might try to do that in debug build. You should not do so in release (production) build because DLLs should generally not do that.

I guess `rundll32.exe` is windows application.